# Is there a way to programmatically download large files from Netsuite?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript, suitescript2.0

I have some saved searches that I stored in files in the file cabinet and I would like to programmatically download these files but I run into Netsuite’s 10mb file size limitation. I have scoured the suitescript documentation but nothing jumps out to me as a solution. Is there some way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We recently downloaded a few million files from Netsuite. We didn't use SuiteScript, due to the limitations (like you describe) and the cost. If that ***isn't*** a requirement, you can use the [Python SDK](https://pypi.org/project/netsuitesdk/) (Uses the SOAP API) for Netsuite. We were regularly pulling files >50 MB with code similar to this:

```py
from netsuitesdk import NetSuiteConnection
import logging
def connect() -> NetSuiteConnection:
    token = oauth.Token(key=TOKEN_KEY, secret=TOKEN_SECRET)
    consumer = oauth.Consumer(key=CONSUMER_KEY, secret=CONSUMER_SECRET)
    NS_ACCOUNT = NETSUITE_ACCOUNT
    NS_CONSUMER_KEY = consumer.key
    NS_CONSUMER_SECRET = consumer.secret
    NS_TOKEN_KEY = token.key
    NS_TOKEN_SECRET = token.secret
    nc = NetSuiteConnection(
        account=NS_ACCOUNT,
        consumer_key=NS_CONSUMER_KEY,
        consumer_secret=NS_CONSUMER_SECRET,
        token_key=NS_TOKEN_KEY,
        token_secret=NS_TOKEN_SECRET,
        caching_path="./netsuite_cache/",
    )
    logging.warn("Connected to NetSuite")
    return nc

def download_file(nc: NetSuiteConnection, file_id: str) -> bytes:
    logging.warn(f"Getting file content for ID {file_id}")
    file = nc.files.get(internalId=file_id)
    return file.content
```

To use this code, you need to have the file ID you want to download. However, you can easily get this list from NetSuite (either with the SOAP API or through a manual export in the UI).

**NOTE: You will need to get the details for `TOKEN_KEY`, `TOKEN_SECRET`, `CONSUMER_KEY`, `CONSUMER_SECRET`, and `NETSUITE_ACCOUNT` from your NetSuite administrator. [See the oracle docs for more details on how to generate these.](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/saas/netsuite/ns-online-help/section_N3445710.html#bridgehead_4489663579)**